# Chrome Workspaces - Saves changes in Sources tab but not Elements

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to setup and use Workspaces on Canary and I'm running into a few issues.

I understand that is still under development but could someone clarify these issues i'm having aren't or are related to the fact that its still under development?

Basically I setup a workspace in DevTools, locating the directory on my file system. Do I need to put anything in URL prefix and folder path input boxes? I've experimented leaving them blank, filling them in etc, but due to the lack of documentation I'm not sure what the correct input is.

Most of the time I run my sites through MAMP so will custom server names alter the configuration?

When I then open open the page I am editing, open the dev tools, make changes in the elements styles sidebar, it doesn't save any changes to the file on my system. But then when I go into the Sources tab and locate the workspace from the slide-out menu on the left, I can make changes to the files directly there. But I have to refresh the browser to see any changes.

I know something isn't quite right because when I watched Paul Irish's little demo a while back, he was making changes in the elements styles bar and seeing the results without refresh and changes being saved automatically. How can I get that this point?

Thanks in advance.

PS. If someone could add chrome-canary and chrome-workspaces tags, that would be great.

Comment: The chrome-canary tag would be pretty useless, because in three months, today's Canary is just an old version. There are about 10 questions about the workspace (formerly called "snippets") feature. Can you give compelling reasons for adding a new tag?

Comment: Only reason I asked was so that my question could reach people in the know.
If its so useless why was it one of the recommend tags when I started typing?
I understand you want the questions posted here to be valid long after they are answered, but as someone requiring support, that isnt my priority.

Comment: I've seen some chrome/devtools engineers following the google-chrome-devtools tag. Given the relatively low volume of questions in this tag, your question will probably be seen when he's online.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue - I have mapped my HTML file to a resource, but making changes requires a refresh.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram: DevTools have never supported HTML live-editing.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov oh well, that explains it then. :)

Answer (score 5):

Once you have added a local filesystem, right-click a local file in your Sources panel and choose "Map to Network Resource", then select the network resource it corresponds to. That should set up the right mapping automatically.

Comment: I don't see this option. I only see "Map to file system resource". I am using chrome stable 28, should i use canary?

Comment: If you right-click a network file, you get the option to `Map to a file system resource`; conversely if you right-click a local file (in a workspace) you get the option to `Map to network resource`

Answer (score 0):

URL prefix and folder path should correspond to the root of your app (the root url, on the server) and the root folder of your app in the file-system respectively.  Alexander Pavlov is correct - if you set the network mapping for an individual file, and restart Dev Tools, these mappings will be made for the entire map, automatically as Dev tools makes the connections.  In other words, do it for one file and you may not have to fill in those fields for the workspace yourself, Dev tools will do it automatically.  Very handy.